# Can Two Compact, Non-Separating Subsets of the Plane be Separated by Jordan Curves?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, geometric-topology, plane-geometry, continuum-theory

Suppose $X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ are compact, mutually disjoint, and neither separates the plane.

How does one prove that there are disjoint Jordan curves $J_1, J_2$ such that $X$ is in the interior region of $J_1$, $Y$ is in the interior region of $J_2$, and neither of $J_1, J_2$ is contained in the interior region of the other?

The requirements on $X$ and $Y$ are necessary; for example, take two disjoint circles, one inside the other.  Or consider the graph of $|\frac{1}{x}|$.  The above theorem can be proven using the classification of non-compact surfaces, but that's too big a cannon for my purposes; I want something elementary.  Schoenflies, JCT, Zoretti etc. is fine, but nothing too beyond that!

If $X$ or $Y$ is connected then it's known due to either some algebraic topology results or Zoretti's Theorem, but in my case I'll be dealing with Cantor sets; I am concocting a proof of the Denjoy-Riesz Theorem that's actually readable and have put one together, but there's a somewhat tedious step that I'd like to simplify before I post it, if possible.

Thanks a lot!  The specific case that if $X, Y$ are Cantor Sets is also of interest; that's the tedious step in my Denjoy-Riesz proof.  I proved it using finite covers of open balls, some geometric arguments about these piecewise-nice neighborhoods, then further subdividing and filling in to avoid one neighborhood 'wrapping around' the neighborhood of the other Cantor set.  It's not an aesthetic proof.

Comment: I suspect this is not too hard starting with Urysohn's Lemma to get a continuous $f : S^1 \to [0,1]$ with $f^{-1}(0)=X$ and $f^{-1}(1)=Y$, and working from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch how can do it. Drawing a picture will be helpful.

$X,Y$ have distance $d > 0$. Therefore we can cover $X,Y$ by disjoint compact subpolyhedra $P, Q$ of $\mathbb R^2$ (e.g. unions of sufficiently small squares). Next we take disjoint regular neigborhoods $M, N$ of $P, Q$. These are compact PL manifolds with boundary. Note that the boundaries of $M, N$ are disjoint from $X, Y$ since $X,Y$ are contained in the manifold interiors $\mathring{M}, \mathring{N}$.

Let us first consider $M$. It has only finitely many components; their interiors cover $X$. Let $C$ be one them; it is a compact PL manifold with boundary. Then $X_C = X \cap C$ is compact and does not intersect $\partial C \subset \partial M$.

We shall cut off pieces of $C$ to obtain a PL copy $D_C$ of the disk $D^2$ such that $X_C \subset D_C \subset C$ and $X \cap \partial D_C = \emptyset$.

It is known that $C$ has the form $C = D^* \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n \mathring D_i$ where
$D^*, D_1, \ldots, D_n$ are PL disks such that $D_i \subset \mathring D^*$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$ and $D_i \cap D_j = \emptyset$ for $i \ne j$. It is of course possible that $n = 0$, i.e. $C = D^*$, but this is the trivial case. So let $n > 0$. Pick $x^* \in \partial D^*$ and $x_1 \in \partial D_1$. Since $X$ does not disconnect $\mathbb R^2$, there is a path $u$ from $x^*$ to $x_1$ which avoids $X$. Thus the distance between $u(I)$ and $X$ is positive. There is a PL path $v$ from $x^*$ to $x_1$ which is so close to $u$ that it also avoids $X$. We can modify $v$ as follows: If $v$ enters some $D_j$ at time $t$ and leaves it at time $s > t$, we can replace $v$ on $[t,s]$ by a PL path in $\partial D_j$. Similarly, if $v$ enters $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \mathring D^*$ and leaves it at time $s > t$, we can replace $v$ on $[t,s]$ by a PL path in $\partial D^*$. Thus we may assume w.l.o.g. that $v$ is a path $C$ which avoids $X$. As the next step we choose a PL path $w$ in $C$ from $x^*$ to $X_1$ which so close to $v$ that it avoids $X$ and has the property $w((0,1)) \subset \mathring C$ ("pushing $v$ away from the boundary''). W.l.o.g. we may assume thet $w$ is a PL embedding (if it is not, we remove possible loops between points of self-intersection). Now choose a regular neigborhood $W$ ot $w(I)$ in $C$ which is so small that it avoids $X$ ("thickening of $w$ to a strip connecting $\partial D^*$ and $\partial D_1$''). There is a PL homeomorphism $h : I \times I \to W$ such that $h(\{0\} \times I) \subset \partial D^*$, $h(\{1\} \times I) \subset \partial D_1$ and $h((0,1) \times I) \subset \mathring C$. Then $C' =  C \setminus h(I \times (0,1))$ is again a PL manifold neigborhood of $X$ having the form $C' = D_1^* \setminus \bigcup_{i=2}^n \mathring D_i$ with a PL disk $D^*_1$. Proceeding inductively we end with a PL disk $D$  such that $X_C \subset D_C \subset C$ and $X \cap \partial D_C = \emptyset$.

Now let $C_1,\ldots, C_m$ be the components of $M$ and assume that they are reduced to disks as above. They cover $X$ and their boundaries do not intersect $X$. Similarly let $C'_1,\ldots, C'_r$ be the components of $N$ and assume that they are reduced to disks. By a similar approach as above we can find a a strip $W_1$ connecting $\partial C_1$ and $\partial C_2$ and avoiding all other $C_i$ and $C'_j$. Then $\bar C_2 = C_1 \cup W_1 \cup C_2$ is a PL disk whose boundary does not intersect $X$.  Proceeding inductively we end with a PL disk $\bar C_m$ containing $X$ in its interior and being disjoint from $N$. Doing the same with the $C'_j$ results in a PL disk $\bar C'_r$ containing $Y$ in its interior and being disjoint from $\bar C_m$. The boundaries of $\bar C_m$ and $\bar C'_r$ are the desired Jordan curves.

Comment: Nice!  In bed I wondered if this works: if one of ur polygonal regions (i.e. finite unions of circles from the $\epsilon$-nbhds) winds around another, just start further subdividing until it breaks apart.  It's fine if you get annuli at the 2nd stage, you can just fill in since these annular regions are in the original $\epsilon$-nbhd away from the other set.  If BWOC it never breaks apart, you'll take the nested intersection and get a continuum which separates the plane (a proper circle-like continuum).  Just not sure how to prove it separates, cuz it might be some pseudo-circle monster thing

Comment: Like, for Cantor sets specifically it's enough that any sort of continuum shows up, so this is defo the easier way for Cantor sets.  But these fucking picky, subtle plane problems are such jerks, not sure how to prove rigorously without dipping into -different- advanced theory that it separates.

Comment: Ah, maybe for my version it's possible to shrink the $\epsilon$ continuously and use a continuity argument for the (dis)connectedness.  I think it works.